# Remote off-site Printer

Tags: ssh, printing

Goal: send print jobs to a remote offsite printer.  Employees should be able to pickup print jobs.  An ubuntu PC or raspberry pi (preferable) would drive said printer.

I found: [How to print through SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26433/how-to-print-over-ssh).  An Asus router is configured for SSH remote access.

Question:  What options are there for me to send print jobs directly to the remote printer.  Perhaps there are other options?

Comment: [use `cups` as print server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html.en).

Comment: that ^. By the way: you could also use google cloud print https://www.google.com/cloudprint#printers

Comment: There is no need for SSH, the printer just needs to be reachable over the network. Use Cups on the RPi to listen for incoming print jobs, by default over TCP port 631.

Comment: @Jos  Thanks for the insight.  The printer is another state and print jobs are to be sent from anywhere on the WWAN